# Q : Why my links are the same when i click on it?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let grandeImage = document.getElementById('full').getAttribute('src');
let redirection = document.getElementById('redirection');

redirection.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (grandeImage == "assets/img/johndoe.png") {

    redirection.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.wikipedia.org');
  };

  if (grandeImage == "assets/img/voyage.png") {

    redirection.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.com');

  };
});
```

```html
<a href="" id="redirection"> <img src="assets/img/johndoe.png" alt="image" id="full"> </a>
```

I have 2 pictures, i want 2 differents links when i click on it, but in my case the 2 pictures return 'www.wikipedia.org'. The 1st picture have to go 'www.wikipedia.org' and the second picture go to 'www.google.com'.

I tried stopPropagation(), but not working.

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Because the image's SRC is not assets/img/voyage.png.

Comment: Where do you have two pictures? There's just one `<img>`

Comment: IDs can't be duplicated, and `getElementById()` only returns the first element with the ID.

Comment: if things are hardcoded in an if, why not just put the urls in the href? keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `grandeImage` is set based on a single DOM element (`#full`) before the click event even happens -- so regardless of what the user clicks on, it'll always contain the same value.

I've rewritten your code to use classes instead of IDs (IDs must be unique). The function now iterates through your 'redirection' links, checks the src of the image *inside that link*, and rewrites the href accordingly. For simplicity's (and accessibility's) sake, this is done once on DOM load instead of waiting until the element is clicked:

```js
// find all the elements:
let redirections = document.querySelectorAll('.redirection');

// iterate through them:
[...redirections].forEach(redirection => {

  // search only inside the current element, instead of the full `document`:
  const grandeImage = redirection.querySelector('.full').getAttribute('src'); // needs to be getAttribute; if you just check `.src` you'll get the full URL including domain

  if (grandeImage == "assets/img/johndoe.png") {
    redirection.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.wikipedia.org');
  }; // consider using an `else` here, or if there are many of these use a `switch`
  if (grandeImage == "assets/img/voyage.png") {
    redirection.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.com');
  }
  
  // just so you can see the results:
  console.log(redirection)
})
```

```html
<a href="" class="redirection"> <img src="assets/img/johndoe.png" alt="image" class="full"> </a>

<a href="" class="redirection"> <img src="assets/img/voyage.png" alt="image" class="full"> </a>
```

(It probably goes without saying that it would be better to generate the correct hrefs in your HTML instead of injecting them via javascript after the fact.)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer , your code is more professionnal than mine , unfortunately the result is the same as mine. I will try to be more simple in my code :)